# Insert into database function

Tags: php

Within my database class I created an insert function. When I test the code no data is placed into the database.

Here is the code that I used:

```
public function insert() {
    if (count($fields)) {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = '';
        $x = 1;
        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`". implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";
    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: And if you print the $SQL statement and run it manually in the SQL console, what happens? why are you suppressing your own error reporting by using `return FALSE;` instead of printing the actual error?

Comment: where did you get that `$fields`? try to print  the value of that, just maybe it's empty since you don't have any assigned value for that.

Comment: Did you mean `$this->fields`? Otherwise, `$fields` should be passed in as a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

Form this code block:

```
 foreach($fields as $field) {
        $values .= ', ';
 }
```

I think the $values value will be ',,,,,' at last. Is it a valid value?